# OpenGL read depth from depth stencil texture

Tags: opengl

Seem to be having trouble reading the depth from a depth / stencil texture.

The depth / stencil texture is setup with the following code:

```
glGenTextures(1, &depth);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth, 0);
```

I then bind this as a texture for reading.

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_TEXTURE_MODE, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_NONE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE, GL_INTENSITY);
```

And read it in the shader

```
uniform sampler2D depthTexture;
...
vec4 depth = texture(depthTexture, gl_FragCoord.xy/screensize);
```

However all I am getting is a black screen?

Comment: to you set the texture for reading in the fragment shader?

`int my_sampler_uniform_location;
my_sampler_uniform_location = GetVariable("depthTexture");
glUniform1iARB(my_sampler_uniform_location, depth);`

Comment: Yes, forgot to post that piece of code. I am calling
    shader.setUniform("depthTexture", 0);
which in turn calls
    glUniform1i(depthTextureUniform, 0)

Comment: Are you setting the `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` parameter on the texture?